# split a record into individual records based of values of list, Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a record RDD like,
firstname, lastname, DoB, age, emails. Here emails is a list:

```
Vikash, Singh, 19-12-1982, 32, {abc@email.com, def@email.com}
```

I wanted to break this into two record like

```
Vikash, Singh, 19-12-1982, 32, abc@email.com
Vikash, Singh, 19-12-1982, 32, def@email.com
```

How can I do it in Scala?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your emails are stored in some sort of `TraversableOnce`, you just need to run a `flatMap`:

```
val rdd2 = rdd1.flatMap { case (first, last, dob, age, emails) => for {email <- emails} yield (first, last, dob, age, email) }
```

When I run locally, I get:

```
scala> val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Vikash", "Singh", "19-12-1982", 32, Seq("abc@email.com", "def@email.com"))))
...
scala> val rdd2 = rdd1.flatMap { case (first, last, dob, age, emails) => for {email <- emails} yield (first, last, dob, age, email) }
...
scala> rdd2.foreach(println)
...
(Vikash,Singh,19-12-1982,32,abc@email.com)
(Vikash,Singh,19-12-1982,32,def@email.com)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based in @Rohan Aletty answer, if you want to use `map` instead a `for loop`:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Vikash", "Singh", "19-12-1982", 32, 
                            Seq("abc@email.com", "def@email.com"))))
val rdd2 = rdd1.flatMap { case (first, last, dob, age, emails) => 
                            emails.map(email => (first, last, dob, age, email)) }

println(rdd2.count()) // => 2
rdd2.collect().foreach(println) // => (Vikash,Singh,19-12-1982,32,abc@email.com), (Vikash,Singh,19-12-1982,32,def@email.com)
```